# How to get line number when multiple strings are matched in the same order

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with multiple occurrences of strings `test1` and `test2`.
I am trying to find the line numbers of the matches found as well as printing those lines according to the ORDER they appear. Each string appears once in a single line.

Here is an example:

```
cat input.txt
this is test1
this is not
this is test2
this is test1
```

My naive try to get the line numbers (and ordering) is

```
grep -n 'test1' input.txt  | cut -d : -f1 > output1.txt
grep -n 'test2' input.txt  | cut -d : -f1 >> output1.txt
sort -k1n output1.txt
```

It's output is

```
cat output1.txt
1
3
4
```

and then for printing using a do-while-loop

```
while read line; do
 if [[ $line =~ test1 || $line =~ test2 ]] ; then
 echo $line >> output2.txt;
done <input.txt
```

The output looks

```
cat output2.txt
this is test1
this is test2
this is test1
```

My question is whether there is any better ( and probably efficient) way for this solution, in particular getting the line numbers according to correct order.
Thanks.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `grep -n 'test1\|test2'` ?

Comment: `output1.txt` and `output2.txt` are the exact outputs. I just want to know if there is a better way to get to `output1.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. It will only place line numbers into output1.txt output file.

```
awk '/this is test[0-9]+/{print FNR}' Input_file > "output1.txt"
```

To get line numbers and contents in different output files(`output1.txt`, `output2.txt`) try following.

```
awk '/this is test[0-9]+/{print FNR > "output1.txt";print $0 > "output2.txt"}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Or taking inspiration from @kamil cuk's comment and a bit enhancing it to get only line numbers.

```
grep -n 'test1\|test2' Input_file | cut -d':' -f1 > "output1.txt"
OR
grep -n 'this is test1\|this is test2' Input_file | cut -d':' -f1 > "output1.txt"
```

To get matched contents into output files try following.

```
grep -n 'this is test1\|this is test2' Input_file | cut -d':' -f2 > "output2.txt"
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `sed`:

To get only line numbers use:

```
sed -n '/test[12]/{=;}'  Input_file > "output1.txt"
```

To get line contents:

```
sed -n '/test[12]/p' Input_file > "output2.txt"
```

Comment: I like the `grep` solution better, since in case of `awk` it is limited to this particular example.  For instance take two random strings `testone` and `testtwo`.

Comment: @Boogeyman, sure glad that it could help you, cheers. In `awk` solution advantage is I have NOT hard coded any test1 or test2 strings so even more strings come eg--> test3, test4 etc they will also be caught(if you need to catch all) with it too.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` itself can do this, why bother?

```
$ grep -E 'test1|test2' input.txt     
this is test1                         
this is test2                         
this is test1
```

If you want the line numbers as well as the contents:

```
$ grep -nE 'test1|test2' input.txt    
1:this is test1                       
3:this is test2                       
4:this is test1                       

$ grep -nE 'test[12]' input.txt       
1:this is test1                       
3:this is test2                       
4:this is test1
```

Or `grep 'test[12]' input.txt` and `grep -n 'test[12]' input.txt`.

And a `sed` way is:

```
sed -n '/test[12]/p' input.txt
```

for line numbers only:

```
sed -n '/test[12]/=' input.txt
```

The advantage of using `awk` is that it can write different results to files within one command:

```
awk '/test[12]/{
    print FNR >"output1.txt"         #line numbers to output1.txt
    print >"output2.txt"             #contents to output2.txt
    print FNR ":" $0 >"output3.txt"  #both to output3.txt
}' input.txt
```